# JavaScript change event not triggering when using .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded up a JavaScript `.change()` event so when a radio button selection is changed different things happen, when I manually make this change the event fires and everything is fine. What is not working is when I call the `.trigger("change")` command on the radio button the event does not appear to be firing since none of the code in the `.change()` call runs. What is the proper way of firing an event via JavaScript code?

Here is the code I use to make the event call:

```
$("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]").trigger("change");
```

And here is the code that should be ran on a change event:

```
$("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]").change(function ()
{
    $("#TimeEntryStartTime").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#TimeEntryEndTime").toggleClass("hidden");
    $("#TimeEntryDuration").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".timeEntryBox").val("");
});
```

As requested the HTML:

```
    <li>
    <label>Time Entry Mode:</label>

    <label class="normal">
        <input type="radio" id="TimeEntryModeTime" name="TimespanEntryMode" value="true" checked="checked" />Time
    </label>

    <label class="normal">
        <input type="radio" id="TimeEntryModeDuration" name="TimespanEntryMode" value="false" />Duration
    </label>
</li>

<li id="TimeEntryStartTime">
    <label>Start Time:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStartDay, Model.DaysOfTheWeek, new { @class = "dayOfTheWeekSelector", @id = "SelectedStartDay" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timeEntryBox", @id = "StartTimeEntryBox", @readonly = "readonly" } })
</li>

<li id="TimeEntryEndTime">
    <label>End Time:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEndDay, Model.DaysOfTheWeek, new { @class = "dayOfTheWeekSelector", @id = "SelectedEndDay" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "timeEntryBox", @id = "EndTimeEntryBox", @readonly = "readonly" } })
</li>

<li id="TimeEntryDuration" class="hidden">
    <label>Duration:</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStartDay, Model.DaysOfTheWeek, new { @class = "dayOfTheWeekSelector", @id = "SelectedDurationStartDay", @Name = "SelectedDurationStartDay" })
    H:@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDurationHour, Model.DurationHours, new { @class = "durationTime", @id = "DurationHour" })
    M:@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDurationMinute, Model.DurationMinutes, new { @class = "durationTime", @id = "DurationMinute" })
</li>
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML as well? It looks like since there are multiple radio buttons, you might need to do it in a different way.

Comment: In browser console past `$("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]")` does it select desired `input` element ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Added the HTML as requested, There are indeed two buttons each with a unique ID but the same `name`. The `.change()` event triggers fine when I click back and forth in a browser.

Comment: @Matthew when and how are you calling the `trigger()`?

Comment: Looks crazy to me. This should work!

Comment: When you trigger the change event, it happens once for each radio button. The first event toggles the classes, and the second event toggles them again, making it look like nothing happened.

Comment: @lamelemon inside a Jquery AJAX success call that is triggered by the users clicking on a row in a table after the page is fully loaded

Comment: @JJJ So how do I make it only fire once?

Comment: Either choose one of the radio buttons and target it directly with an id, or add `:first` to the selector. Or, the best option, make the event a separate function and call the function directly instead of triggering the event.

Comment: Or use `:checked` on your selector for the `trigger()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify one of the radio's you want to trigger the change :

```
$("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]:eq(index_here)").trigger("change");
____________________________________^^^^^^^^^^
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#toggle").on('click', function(){
  $("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]:eq(0)").trigger("change");
});

$("input[name=TimespanEntryMode]").change(function (){
  alert('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>Time Entry Mode:</label>

  <label class="normal">
    <input type="radio" id="TimeEntryModeTime" name="TimespanEntryMode" value="true" checked="checked" />Time
  </label>

  <label class="normal">
    <input type="radio" id="TimeEntryModeDuration" name="TimespanEntryMode" value="false" />Duration
  </label>
</li>

<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
```